# cache distribute framework for PHP

Tags: cassandra, memcached

Currently, looking for cache distribution framework for my php implementation.

mainly, for local or remote cache storage.

i have some idea about "Memcache" & "Apache Cassandra".

is there any more well framework ?

thanks
javaamtho

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/), as it provides a distributed persistent cache that is quite performant and super easy to use.  The problem with Memcached is that it's harder to scale to additional machines, and if a machine goes down you lose all those keys and have to rebuild the cache.  Cassandra also has excellent caching support but is quite a bit more complex; if you don't need the complexity Couchbase is probably a better choice.